# No Material tab when importing usdc file

Tags: materials, import

I'm trying to import materials from AmbientCG but the material tab is missing.

[image]

I'm on blender 4.0 and am using a tutorial from 3.5 so I'm not sure if the way you import usd files changed or not could somebody help me with importing materials?

Comment: In the sidebar on the import screen right? It's there for me in 4.0/4.1.

Comment: Re-opening blender after about an hour did the trick not sure why.